# Playframework 2.2.0-M1 and idea ide

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I em installed scala plugin and play2 plugin in my "idea12". I entered in play console "idea" command.

project launched, but method "ok()" dont work, ide offers me a method to do it again.

[img here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78421444/play.jpg)

Please help me. I like idea and other ide not to my liking. Eclipse disgusting works with scala templates.

Answer (score 1):

You use a wrong name. The status methods are CamelCased: [`Ok`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L880) instead of `ok`.